# What are good online resources to learn using Python to get and post data in a webpage? More generally for webscraping?

Tags: python, post, get, web-scraping

I am not a software engineer and my knowledge of Python is focused on using it fro data wrangling and machine learning modeling.  However, I need to learn how to get and post data to webpages and do webscraping as well.  What are good on line tutorials or courses that would teach me the necessary skills?  I find difficult learning from reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following series of courses, is a very good start for learning python

https://www.class-central.com/mooc/4319/coursera-programming-for-everybody-getting-started-with-python

You might want to focus on the following course in the series:
https://www.class-central.com/mooc/4343/coursera-using-python-to-access-web-data

*About the Course
This course will show how one can treat the Internet as a source of data.  We will scrape, parse, and read web data as well as access data using web APIs.  We will work with HTML, XML, and JSON data formats in Python.  This course will cover Chapters 11-13 of the textbook “Python for Informatics”. To succeed in this course, you should be familiar with the material covered in Chapters 1-10 of the textbook and the first two courses in this specialization.  These topics include variables and expressions, conditional execution (loops, branching, and try/except), functions, Python data structures (strings, lists, dictionaries, and tuples), and manipulating files.  This course covers Python 2.*

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I enrolled to the course and it is really helpful.  Any other suggestions will be most appreciated as well.